# numpy: how to smooth x,y,z values in columns of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, spline

I have accelerometer data—to keep it simple just acceleration—loaded into a numpy array like so (toy data; columns are x,y,z):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline, BSpline
idx = [1,2,3,4]
idx = np.array(idx,dtype=int)
accel = [[-0.7437,0.1118,-0.5367],
         [-0.5471,0.0062,-0.6338],
         [-0.7437,0.1216,-0.5255],
         [-0.4437,0.3216,-0.3255],
]
accel = np.array(accel,dtype=float)
```

I want to smooth these values. I have found an example [here](https://www.statology.org/matplotlib-smooth-curve/) of how to do it with bspline. Trouble is the example uses a 1d array. I'm not yet good enough at Python to figure out how to reproduce this for a 2D array. I can extract a column slice for x and smooth it like so:

```
x = accel[:,0]
idxnew = np.linspace(idx.min(), idx.max(), 200) 
spl = make_interp_spline(idx, x, k=3)
x_smooth = spl(idxnew)
```

But I'm not sure how to write that back into the first column of a new, longer array. I tried

```
accel_sm = []
accel_sm = np.array(idx,dtype=float)
np.hstack(accel_sm,x_smooth)
```

But that throws "TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str". I'm a little stuck. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried to do it with np.concatenate([arr1,arr2,...],axis=1)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that x_smooth is recognized as a vector - but you need to view it as a matrix with one-column -> use reshape.

````
x_smooth = x_smooth.reshape(-1,1)
for i in range(1,accel.shape[1]):
    x = accel[:, i]
    idxnew = np.linspace(idx.min(), idx.max(), 200)
    spl = make_interp_spline(idx, x, k=3)
    x_smooth = np.concatenate([x_smooth,spl(idxnew).reshape(-1,1)],axis=1)```

You can detect the problem via viewing x_smooth.shape which gives (200,) but you need (200,1)
````

Comment: When I try this with the above input, it throws "TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not str" on the last statement of the loop. I have gotten this on previous tries. I have no idea where TF a string could be getting into those arguments!

Answer (score 0):

A friend was able to get this working like so (code added to first block in the OP):

```
ts_length = 200
accel_sm = np.zeros([ts_length,3])
idxnew = np.linspace(idx.min(), idx.max(), ts_length) 
for i in range (0,3):
         c = accel[:,i]
         spl = make_interp_spline(idx, c, k=3)
         c_smooth = spl(idxnew)
         accel_sm[:, i] = c_smooth
print(accel_sm)
```

I had actually tried this approach—assigning the c_smooth to a slice of accell_sm—but it didn't work because I hadn't filled the target with zeros first. I usually code in Perl where don't have to pre-fill arrays, but you do in Python, I have learned.